# Check if unhashable item already in a list/set

Tags: python, python-3.x

I would like to see if an item is already in a list or set. Normally I would do this (if not a dict):

```
items = set()
for nested_item in nested_items:
    items.append(nested_item)
```

However, that gives me an error:

> TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

The only way I'm able to do it now is as follows:

```
items = list()
for nested_item in nested_items:
    if nested_item not in items:
        items.append(nested_item)
```

Is there a better way to do this? Is there a way to still use a `set`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `tuple`s (which are hashable). Mutable objects, like `list`s, are unhashable, while immutable objects, like `tuple`s, are. `set`s and `dict`s rely on hashes internally.

```
items = set()
for nested_item in nested_items:
    items.add(tuple(nested_item))
```

This can also be done in one line:

```
items = set(tuple(nested_item) for nested_item in nested_items)
```

or

```
items = {tuple(nested_item) for nested_item in nested_items}
```

In all three cases, the output will be (given some example `nested_items`):

```
nested_items = [[1, 2], [2, 3], [1, 2], [3, 4], [4, 5], [2, 3]]
items = {(1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4), (4, 5)}
```

Also, be sure to convert any `list`s into `tuple`s when checking for membership:

```
print([1, 2] in items)
# TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

print(tuple([1, 2]) in items)
# True

print((1, 2) in items)
# True
```

Sometimes, a list contains other lists, and a simple `tuple` call is not enough:

```
print(tuple([[1, 2], [3, 4]]))
([1, 2], [3, 4])
```

In this case, use a simple recipe instead for conversion:

```
def to_tuple(t):
    return tuple(map(to_tuple, t)) if isinstance(t, (list, tuple)) else t

to_tuple([1, [2, (3,), [4], [5, 6, 7]], (8, 9)])
(1, (2, (3,), (4,), (5, 6, 7)), (8, 9))
```

Comment: Is it guaranteed that a tuple containing unhashable items can be recreated so it has the same hash? That would be required for comparison.

Comment: @KlausD. Everything would need to be converted into something hashable, unfortunately. For example, list of lists of lists would have to be converted into tuple of tuples of tuples.

Comment: @KlausD. I added a small section to my answer that deals with nested lists.

Answer (score 0):

For sets as well as dictionary keys you have to use hashable objects. This is required since the hash is used in the underlying implementation. Similar types in other might be call hash map, where you can see the importance of the hash right from the name.

If you are able to computer a unique reproducible key for an item you can use a dictionary with the that key and the item as value. If not sets and dictionaries are not the right structures for your problem.

BTW sets use `.add()` instead of `.append()`.